# Why would a stacktrace point to a closing brace in Java?

Tags: java, debugging

What does it mean if you get a `NullPointerException` on a closing brace in Java? Say, for example, right [here](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/v2.9.5/src/main/java/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeParserBucket.java#L521):

```
    SavedState() {
        this.iZone = DateTimeParserBucket.this.iZone;
        this.iOffset = DateTimeParserBucket.this.iOffset;
        this.iSavedFields = DateTimeParserBucket.this.iSavedFields;
        this.iSavedFieldsCount = DateTimeParserBucket.this.iSavedFieldsCount;
    } <-- Stack trace says NPE is thrown here
```

This is in the stacktrace:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket$SavedState.<init>(DateTimeParserBucket.java:521) ~[joda-time-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
...
```

Answer (score 5):

The only reason (barring things being very broken) it would point to a brace is if the source and the code being run aren't in sync. Clean, re-run and see the stacktrace again.

In this case since the stacktrace is coming from inside joda-time, you're probably looking at the source for the wrong version of the library. Make sure you're looking at the source for version `2.9.5`.

Comment: Or there might be some generated code involved, e.g when using Lombok.